# Flask read static jpg image file from disk and store in MySQL database without a form

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

There are plenty of posts about reading a file using Flask from a HTML Form with commands like:

```
file = request.files['inputFile']
```

and storing them into a database which I have successfully managed to do.

However, I am now trying to read a static image file called photo.jpg from /static/images folder and store it in MySQL database without browsing to it.
Sounds like a simple problem but can't seem to find any posts showing how to do it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're dealing with files, so you would just use the [file object](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) in the standard library:

```
target_file = '/wherever/it/lives/static/photo.jpg'
with open(target_file, 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
    # now you have the file contents `data`-- insert that into your mysql blob column.
```